# What is the German equivalent of the term sub-skills?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I googled for the English term **sub-skills** that is especially used in the educational field. And I saw there are three terms that were *Subskills, Teilkompetenz* and *Einzelfertigkeit.* But I don’t like using borrowed words in an actual German sentence.

Which would be the best equivalent of **sub-skills**, I’ve stumbled upon a usage like following in a German text.

> Wichtige Angaben unterscheiden ist eine Einzelfertigkeit (sub-skills) assoziiert mit dem Lesen.

This usage works always?

Comment: I never heard the word subskill (in German or English). But, it think, I would use Teilkompetenz ("Teilkompetenz des Lesens.").

Comment: And you could *really* start following those rules that have been corrected in what seems like each of your questions to date.

Comment: I think, the question is actually more about the differences between: Fähigkeit, Fertigkeit and Kompetenz. Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15277/translation-of-to-maintain-a-skill/15290#15290.

Comment: @Iris  You might be have never heard _Sub-skills_, but maybe you heard _sub_ and _skills_ actually it is like parent child relation, for example Grammatik(Parent) => Modalverben(Child) an another example from web development _sitename.com(Parentdomain)_ => blog.sitename(Subdomain) in my example above while  Das Lesen is parent(superordinate) _Wichtige Angaben unterscheiden_ is child(subordinate).

Answer (score 2):

I would say the following matches best to sub-skills:

- Teilkompetenzen or
- Kenntnisse

They both even match to

- Erfahrungen mit

but you should be fine with the ones above

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. As you might see, I improved your posts formatting with better bullet points. You can find more information about the Markdown syntax and any other questions you may have about the site in the [help].